# Kernel Stack Virtual Address

Tags: linux, kernel, osdev

Is the linux **kernel stack** at the same virtual address in each process context?

Before answer, please note that I've specified the KERNEL stack and not the user space one.

Comment: Every kernel thread has its own stack. Because whole kernel shares the same virtual address space, kernel's stacks should be different for different threads.

Comment: Assuming that I have a single thread cpu. I deduce that all the processes kernel stacks are mapped to the same virtual address. Agree?

Comment: Do not understand you. Lets kernel thread **T1** has stack **S1**, and thread **T2** has stack **S2**. If you talk about *single stack for different threads*, then yes, stack **S1** has the same virtual address for both **T1** and **T2**. If you talk about *stack addresses for their own threads*, then address of **S1** differs from one of **S2**.

Comment: Ok, i try to re-elaborate. Live alone the threads and think about two processes (tasks) running in a single core cpu (no multithread and no SMP). They have two different physical stacks at two different physical addresses. I was wondering if the physical addresses are mapped to the same virtual address.

Comment: `I was wondering if the physical addresses are mapped to the same virtual address.` - No. As I explained in the first comment, all kernel threads live in the **same virtual address space**. Within that space, different physical addresses cannot be mapped into the same virtual address. It is simply impossible to create such address space.

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev for your replies. But, once again, maybe I was not clear.
First, it is possible to have multiple **processes** map their private kernel stacks to the same virtual address (via paging). Is possible because I'm doing it :). When a syscall begin they simply map their private stack into the "common" virtual address.

Maybe you are confusing threads with processes. Obviously multiple kernel threads cannot share the same stack virtual address (otherwise they cannot have their private stack frames to store automatic variables and function call return addresses).

Comment: `When a syscall begin they simply map their private stack into the "common" virtual address. ` - You may write such kernel. But none of *existing* kernels I am aware of don't use such approach. There is no confusion with threads and processes in the kernel: In Linux kernel only **threads** exist; these threads corresponds both to *user threads* and *user processes*. And all *kernel threads* share the **same virtual space**. "Same" means that every physical address is mapped to the same virtual address for every thread. No exceptions.

Comment: Understood. Do you know the motivation? To me looks like is a waste of virtual address space. The only motivation I see would be if one process needs to access to another process kernel stack. But I don't think that is the case. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you correctly understand me. `The only motivation would be if one process needs to access to another process kernel stack. But I don't think that is the case.` - It is actually **the case**. Thread may allocate some struct at his stack, publich pointer to it, and go to sleep. Other threads may access struct allocated on the sleeping thread's stack. `To me looks like is a waste of virtual address space.` - This is rarely a problem when writting a kernel. As opposite, having different page tables for different threads would consume more **physical memory**, which is much worse.

Comment: Very clear! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have only one core then you only need one kernel stack. If you have more than one core than is possible two or more cores execute kernel code so there will be problem if two cores use the same stack. Of course kernel must map all the stacks to all virtual address spaces because the different stack is per cpu not per process and a process may run by two cpus (not the same time) and they will need to find at every process virtual address space his own stack.